# Why does SQL foribben to execute SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to execute query in phpmyadmin and get error:

```
#1142 - SELECT command denied to user 'cpses_tkdpmnyjWW'@'localhost' for table 'user'
```

So, user `cpses_tkdpmnyjWW'@'localhost` is created dynamically and I can not set privileges for this user.
How to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can not set privileges for this user"? Why not? If you were able to create it, you obviously do have write access to the user accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SHOW GRANTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-grants.html) to show your current user privileges. It sounds as though the output may be similar to:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'Unnamed'@'localhost'
```

This would mean the account could sign into the server but do little else. [This page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html) gives a more detailed breakdown, as you'll see there are quite a few permutations.

The solution is you need to either find an account with more privileges or create/update one.

If the above is not an option, one quick trick I may try is connecting to '127.0.0.1' instead of 'localhost'. In MySQL the source of the connection can form part of the username so it's plausible that connecting on an IP instead of socket if you are on Unix flavoured OS.

Additionally, if you have admin/root access to the server, it is possible to create users when MySQL starts which is very useful in some scenarios.

Comment: Problem is that I can not set `GRANT` for user if currently session, because after user will be changed.

Comment: Hi Muhah, could you clarify? I think askaschas comment is relevant. Perhaps explain in your question how the user account is being created.

Comment: This account is temporarily in phpmyadmin for current session

Comment: Ok, who controls the code/system that makes the temporary account? It sounds as though it may not be giving the temporary account the right privileges;

Comment: I dont know, I have only one created account, but syste, works under others accounts

Comment: Ok, so when you created the account. Did you give it any privileges? By default an account can do almost nothing in MySQL. You need to give it privileges to SELECT and so on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90741/discussion-between-muhad-and-steve-e).

Comment: Yes, I have set all privileges for my account, but system works under temp account

Comment: sorry, time up - kids are awake!